# webpack-dev-server not serving index.html generated by HtmlWebPackPlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have the following `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    mode: "development",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: { extensions: ["*", ".js"] },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/dist/"),
        publicPath: "/dist/",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: __dirname,
        port: 3000,
        publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist/",
        proxy: {
            '/api' : {
                target: 'http://localhost:8000',
                secure: false
            }
        },
        hot: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            hash: true,
            template: "./src/index.html",
            filename: "index.html"
        })
    ],
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()]
    }
};
```

When I run `webpack-dev-server`, everything compiles fine, but when I navigate to `localhost:3000/public/dist/index.html`, I get a "file not found" error.

However, when I run `webpack --mode development`, the `index.html` file is correctly written to `public/dist` and I'm able to open it on my web browser.

I'm not sure why this file is correctly written when webpack is run normally, but not when the dev server is ran. I know the webpack dev server serves files from memory so I don't expect it to show up on my filesystem but I at least expect to be able to open it from the browser.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack dev server doesn't actually build the files to your project directory.  From [their docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/):

> webpack-dev-server doesn't write any output files after compiling. Instead, it keeps bundle files in memory and serves them as if they were real files mounted at the server's root path.

So running `webpack-dev-server`, you shouldn't expect to see any built files (like your resultant index.html) in your dist directory.  It will be serving the project from memory directly to your `localhost:3000`, or whatever pathname you choose.  However, running `webpack` actually builds the files to your destination directory, and you'll find them there.  Hope that clears it up for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I won't get the benefit of hot reloading when the `index.html` changes right? For example, if I have `hash: true` I would like `index.html` to point to a new (hashed) `bundle.js` upon every change, which means I would have to run `webpack` every time.

Comment: that is true.  and i am actually having the same problem right now while working on full stack apps.  its a pain in the butt to rebuild every time.  im sure there are solutions using a liveserver or something similar, but i don't expect to find a solution within webpack.  webpack and webpack dev server are doing their respective jobs in your scenario